# Is it possible to fix version for pip upgrade?

Tags: pip, version, bitbucket, package

I want to ran something like this:

```
pip install --upgrade pip#some_version
pip install git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/my_project/my_package.git#some_version
```

I want to use packages with fixed version, but is it possible to have in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the repository has tags for releases, you can install a specific version like this

```
pip install git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/my_project/my_package.git@tag
```

Tags can be created and pushed to remote like this

```
git tag -a v1.0 <commit ID>
git push origin v1.0
```

Pip can be downgraded like this, although I wouldn't recommend it

```
pip install pip==8.1.2
```

Comment: I don't think you should freeze the version for `pip`. The latest stable release is always the best, and pip itself tells you so. The pip version doesn't have any impact on the available packages.

Comment: I added info on how to install a specific `pip` version. Pleas accept the answer if you are happy with it :)